# Google Closure Compiler incorrectly removes function call

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-closure-compiler, phaser-framework

I am developing a HTML5 game, using Phaser and the Google Closure Compiler in advanced mode in order to package the game.

I've ran into an issue where it seems I am unable to destroy a sprite. After checking the output from the compiler I noticed that it keeps removing my destroy function call.

My code is very simple, I've tested the following:

`sprite.destroy();` and `Phaser.Component.Destroy.prototype.destroy.call(sprite);`

Both of these lines simply get removed from my codebase. It's not because it's unreachable code, if I put `console.log` statements in the same scope they stay there.

So the original code is this:

```
if (typeof this.sprite != 'undefined'){
    console.log('destroy sprite');
    this.sprite.destroy();
    Phaser.Component.Destroy.prototype.destroy.call(this.sprite);
    console.log('sprite destroyed');
}
```

And it gets compiled to this:

```
"undefined"!=typeof this.sprite&&(console.log("destroy sprite"),console.log("sprite destroyed"))
```

I can't figure out why the code is removed, Phaser is set as an external and I'm not running into this issue with any other methods or phaser classes.

Simply calling `eval('this.sprite.destroy();');` works by the way. This proves that the function does actually exist. However this is a pretty shitty solution, and only works because the compiler isn't replacing `sprite` in this case.

**UPDATE**

I've been able to reliably reproduce the issue with very little code, see my answer below. But I don't know why this is happening yet.

**UPDATE 2**

Thanks to Hacketo we figured out that this issue occurs because a proper Phaser extern file is missing. Creating one specifically for this issue fixes it, however without a full file there will always be a chance for more issues.

For this specific issue, adding the following file as an extern fixed it: http://pastebin.com/nXA0fiZr

Comment: is the closure compiler set to `ADVANCED` mode ?

Comment: yes, for me that's the whole point of using the closure compiler

Comment: Then `this.sprite` should have been renamed right ? Did you add type annotation on this property ?

Comment: To be honest I don't know why it's not replacing `this.sprite`. I'm not using any type annotations. There's multiple variables in my end code that are not being replaced but I'm not sure why. Maybe because `sprite` is also used in Phaser and it doesn't want to accidentally replace it?

Comment: Is this code supposed to be in an class that extends from a Phaser Component ? [Annotations should be used](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler?hl=en), then closure compiler know that your class has a property called `sprite` and it's a `Phaser.Sprite` that has a `destroy` method

Comment: Nope, it's a separate class that doesn't extend anything. I'm using TypeScript and from TypeScript it's set as a Phaser.Sprite. I just declare the sprite normally as a property so there's no magic stuff going on.  I'll look into type annotation because I haven't used that yet, but it doesn't seem like that should be needed.

Comment: Could you try to add `/** @type {Phaser.Sprite} */` on the line before the declaration of `this.sprite` (in the javascript one)

Comment: What I said before (removed comment) wasn't true. In this testcase http://pastebin.com/qxX22auh it does work, the code doesn't get removed. So it must be something else in my code or the overall structure causing the issue, since I'm not going to post the full codebase I guess I'll have to figure it out myself. I'll be removing stuff from my class until I get it to keep the destroy function or something. Adding type annotation didn't work either.

Comment: You said that Phaser is set as external, but which externs file did you used to define it ? ([example of an extern file](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/contrib/externs/jquery-1.9.js))

Comment: Hmm, I'm just using the minified js file. I can't seem to find any file with all the typedefs like you provided. I figured out another weird thing, this test code: http://pastebin.com/APS5sAyx works if I compile it by itself. If I compile it with the rest of my codebase it doesn't (the destroy is removed). So extra code somewhere is causing it to remove the destroy method.

Comment: I've figured out what causes it, but not yet why. See my answer below. I have a different (completely unrelated) class with a destroy method, it having that method for some reason causes this issue.

Comment: this may be because the extern file is not an extern file and `this.sprite` is not typed with the annotation. Could you try to remove the closure stuff ?

Comment: What do you mean remove the closure stuff? I'm working from TypeScript and I don't really have an impact on the output from there. If Google fails on the closures then that's a closure compiler issue right?

Comment: Well I'm only guessing, but as you don't use annotations the compiler might not understand all you code ([are you using something like this ?](https://github.com/evanw/typescript-closure-compiler)). I tested with the online compiler, could you try to use this simple [extern file](http://pastebin.com/EbX3yxjZ)

Comment: Well, that worked (apart from the tiny syntax error at the end there ;))! I still think it's weird behaviour how it completely removes a function call like that, but I suppose it's hard to be reliable if you don't know anything about the code. If you post this as an answer I will select it, thanks a lot for the help! BTW I am using grunt-typescript and npm closurecompiler.

Comment: Also, the Phaser.Game part is not needed here. I was running into some other issues of code that seemingly isn't (properly) executed. I'll be adding to this file to see if I can fix the other issues with it as well. I don't really understand why 'destroy' is the only thing this is happening to, my codebase isn't that small.

Comment: Turns out this: http://pastebin.com/nXA0fiZr is the least amount of code I need to get it to work. I think because the destroy method is dynamically added through `Phaser.Component.Core.install`. Apparently it's not about the annotations, just that google reads `Phaser.Sprite.prototype.destroy`

Comment: It removed the function call because in your example there is no extern definition and the function does nothing so it's an optimization. It may not be the only thing that is not properly compiled, you said in past comment that `sprite` was not the only variable that wasn't renamed. Annotations are here to typecheck at compile time and help the compiler to understand your code as best as possible, they are not required. What you need now is to find/make an extern file for Phaser. I could write an answer but I can only say that you need a proper extern file.

Comment: Thanks, I already found another thing that didn't properly compile. I'll be working on an extern file to resolve my issues, I probably won't end up writing a full one though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out what's causing this, however why it's causing it I don't know so if anybody has a clue I'm very interested.

Here is a sample that allows you to reproduce my issue:

Typescript: http://pastebin.com/YaCfH2mz

Javascript: http://pastebin.com/A4w2YG9N

So for some reason, defining a method called `destroy` in a random class for some reason breaks everything. Even though the class is not used, and the method is empty.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Hacketo we figured out that this issue occurs because a proper Phaser extern file is missing. Creating one specifically for this issue fixes it, however without a full file there will always be a chance for more issues.

For this specific issue, adding the following file as an extern fixed it:

```
var Phaser = {};
 
Phaser.Sprite = function(game, x, y, key, frame){};
 
Phaser.Sprite.prototype.destroy = function(){};
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler believes that `this.sprite.destroy()` has no side effects.  That's where the issue lies.  If you can post the source for the destroy function, I will update this answer.

Comment: The function comes from these two: https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/v2.4.2/src/gameobjects/Sprite.js + https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/v2.4.2/src/gameobjects/components/Destroy.js however that shouldn't matter as it is an extern. And in my testcase: http://pastebin.com/qxX22auh it doesn't happen.